# What happened to the Facebook ASP (MVC) SDK?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

The .net SDK is apparently actively being developed.

So why are features being dropped so rapidly? Are they being put into a different project?

There used to be extension DLLs for web specific features (to handle login, etc.) and special MVC features (an authentication attribute) but now they are nowhere to be found.

There are even functions missing from the main client object like the query function.

So my question is  - should I be developing these features myself or did they just get moved somewhere?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to one of the guys that maintains the Facebook C# SDK:

> The overall goal of Version 6.0 is simplicity. We are reducing the API
>   surface, improving the documentation, and building out better samples
>   to make it even easier to build a Facebook app for .Net or any flavor
>   of Windows.

Source:  http://ntotten.com/2012/02/07/facebook-c-sdk-road-map/

And though the SDK has really made our life easier in making Facebook request, I have not seen much improvement in the documentation as of yet.

Comment: So does that mean that every person should reinvent the wheel? Would anyone like to join me in creating an opensource project where we all work together on creating the building blocks of a facebook .net API? I am thinking of starting with an authentication attribute requiring certain permissions for different page.